# PermitRootLogin in sshd_config needed for OpsWorks?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, opsworks

I've been poking around my OpsWorks instances and just realized they all appear to be configured with `PermitRootLogin without-password`. While this is more secure than `PermitRootLogin yes` I'd really like to disable this entirely on some specific instances. I have not been able to find any specific details on this topic or ROOT ssh access in general in the docs or through the usual methods of research.

Is this setting **required** for by AWS, OpsWorks, or some other
    service or utility?

Comment: what for? Do you have any specific reason why would you want to disable it?

Comment: Just added security. There is no reason (sudo is enabled for a utility) for root to be logging in over SSH. Again, unless I'm missing something done by AWS/OpsWorks. In addition I just went a reviewed a test output of AWS Inspector and they even flag the setting as a moderate level of bad.

Comment: Sorry. It was wrongly stated question. I meant why would you want to disable this option = allow root login over `ssh`.

Comment: Hmmm, too many double negatives maybe...? I **don't** want the root account to be able to ssh into these instances. This appears to be a default setting by AWS/OpsWork and I'd like to set `without-password` to `no` and disable the ability to ssh into the instance with root account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you know that your `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is empty and also the global one (`/etc/security/authorized_keys` -- not sure if always enabled and used, probably not), the behavior is **the same** as if there was `PermitRootLogin no`, *until* somebody with root access will put his key to this file. But with such privileges, *someone* can do a lot of more nasty stuff.

Also if you screw up your `sudoers` file, it is useful to have some spare key in safe place so you can fix it (but I think there is always the way through the web console or something, so this case is no big threat).

About the requirement, I don't see any reason why it should be.

Comment: Sorry, got distracted and botched the comment:

/root/.ssh/authorized_keys is not empty which was one of my concerns with disabling at the sshd_config level. Now that I've looked closer at that entry I see it actually refers the user to login with the utility account that comes default: no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"[utilityaccnt]\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa ------ ---- and kills the connection. Funny thing is AWS flags their own configuration as a security issue.